# How to prove this limit of Airy Function.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, special-functions

I have no idea how to prove this limit

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\exp\left ( \frac{2x^{3/2}}{3} \right )\sqrt[4]{x}\mathrm{Ai}\left ( x \right )=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi }}$$
>   where $\mathrm{Ai}(x)$ is [Airy Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

The asymptotics of Airy function (see [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.7) and [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryAi/introductions/Airys/ShowAll.html)  ) is given by $$\text{Ai}(x)=e^{-\frac{2 x^{3/2}}{3}} \left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{x}}}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{5
   \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{7/4}}{96 \sqrt{\pi
   }}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{13/4}\right)\right)$$ So,

$$\exp\left ( \frac{2x^{3/2}}{3} \right )\sqrt[4]{x}\mathrm{Ai}\left ( x \right )=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{5 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}}{96 \sqrt{\pi
   }}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Comment: Excellent!Thank you(•̀ω•́)

Comment: You are welcome ! If I may give you a trick : when you have things like that, search for *asymptotic behaviour of function $F$*

Comment: I will.(≧ω≦)/Thank you again(•̀ω•́)

Comment: In addition,can you see my another question.http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1628822/286825

Comment: I saw it but it makes to me a lot of problems. I am still thinking about it. I shall let you know if anything comes out from the old brain.

Comment: Much obliged for your help in my math study.         PS:My English is not so good.