# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, zeta-functions

I have some trouble in evaluating this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x$$
I tried to calculate the integral first, but after that I found the series become so complicated.
Besides, I found maybe the series equals to 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{k}\zeta \left ( 2k+\dfrac{3}{2} \right )}{2k+\dfrac{3}{2}}$$
this is definitely a monster to me. So I want to know is there a good way to solve this integral-series.

Comment: Its numerical value is about $1.5301321254055419047226345952830\ldots$

Comment: @Lucian I know,but how to evaluate the closed form took me a long time and I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: I am not sure if the following may be useful, but WolframAlpha does have an exact antiderivative (http://bit.ly/1JFQ2hr) for the summand. For x=0, the antiderivative evaluates to zero, so the summand proves to be the antiderivative of the function evaluated at 1/n. I am not sure if this can be summed using standard techniques / simplifies the summation.

Comment: Using the integral representation of the Zeta function http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta/07/01/01/, you can recast your sum in the integral form $$
\int_0^\infty dt\ \frac{4 \sqrt{t} \, _1F_2\left(1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};-\frac{t^2}{4}\right)}{\left(3 \sqrt{\pi }\right) (\mathrm{e}^t-1)}
$$, which does not seem to have a simple closed form either...but may be simpler to analyze

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo, this integral seems to heavily dominated by the region around $0_+$, this should in principle be good enough to find a nice approximation.

Comment: $=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\sqrt{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{2k}\mathrm{d}x=\sum_k(-1)^k\sum_n\int_0^{1/n}x^{2k+1/2}\mathrm{d}x$ yiels the $\zeta$-function formula.

Comment: $$\zeta(2k+3/2) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2k+1/2}}{(2k+1/2)!}\cdot\frac{dx}{e^x-1}\,dx $$
gives
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1/n}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^x-1}\underbrace{\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{(2k+3/2)!}}_{f(x)} \,dx$$
where
$$ f(x) = \frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2},\qquad g(x)=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{i^m x^{m}}{(m+3/2)!}=\frac{1}{x^{2}}\left(\frac{2ix}{\sqrt{\pi}}-e^{ix}\sqrt{i x}\,\text{Erf}(\sqrt{ix})\right) $$

$$ f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}\text{Re}\left(e^{ix}\sqrt{ix}\,\text{Erf}(\sqrt{ix})\right) $$

Answer (score 5):

Let 
$$I(n) = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x.$$
Substitution:
$$x = t^2,\quad \mathrm{d}x = 2t\mathrm{d}t:$$
$$I(n) = \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\frac{2t^2}{1+t^{4}}\mathrm{d}t.$$
$$I(n) = \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\frac{2}{t^2 + \dfrac{1}{t^2}}\mathrm{d}t.$$
$$I(n) = \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\frac{1-\dfrac1{t^2}}{\left(t + \dfrac{1}{t}\right)^2-2}\mathrm{d}t + \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\frac{1+\dfrac1{t^2}}{\left(t - \dfrac{1}{t}\right)^2+2}\mathrm{d}t.$$
$$I(n) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left.\ln\left|\frac{t + \dfrac{1}{t}-\sqrt 2}{t + \dfrac{1}{t}+\sqrt 2}\right|\right|_0^{\frac1{\sqrt n}} + \dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\left.\arctan\dfrac{ {t - \dfrac{1}{t}}}{\sqrt2}\right|_0^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}.$$
$$I(n) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln\frac{n - \sqrt {2n} + 1}{n + \sqrt {2n} + 1} + \dfrac1{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\dfrac{n - 1}{\sqrt{2n}}\right), \quad I(1) = \dfrac{\pi}{4\sqrt2}.$$
or
$$I(n) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln\frac{1 -\dfrac{\sqrt{2n}}{n + 1}}{1 +\dfrac{\sqrt{2n}}{n + 1}} + \dfrac1{2\sqrt{2}}\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{2n}}{n - 1}, \quad I(1) = \dfrac{\pi}{4\sqrt2}.$$
**UPD**
Maclaurin series is as follows:
$$
I(n) = \dfrac{\sqrt n}{n+1}\left(1+\dfrac13\dfrac{2n}{(n+1)^2}+\dfrac15\dfrac{(2n)^2}{(n+1)^4}+\dots++\dfrac1{2k+1}\dfrac{(2n)^k}{(n+1)^{2k}}+\dots\right)$$$$+\dfrac12\,\dfrac{\sqrt n}{n-1}\left(1-\dfrac13\dfrac{2n}{(n-1)^2}+\dfrac15\dfrac{(2n)^2}{(n-1)^4}-\dots+\dfrac1{2k+1}\dfrac{(-2n)^k}{(n-1)^{2k}}+\dots\right),
$$
$$I(1) = \dfrac{\pi}{4\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: And then, one "just" have to sum...

Comment: @mickep at least not integrate

Comment: I dont't understand why downvote this answer. This result is in a very simple (and explicit) form, comparing with any other approximation or $\zeta$ function

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it becomes more complicated if you integrate first.

Comment: @SiXUlm Moreover, now we can change the order of summation and get analogue of the $\zeta$ function

Comment: The $\ln$ part is negative. Why is it absent from the evaluation of $I(1),$ and counted positively in the Maclaurin series?

Comment: ...and the coefficient in front of $\arctan$ should be $\frac1{\sqrt2},$ not $\frac1{2\sqrt2}.$